# $ \left ( \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} {b_i}^2} \right) \le k \left (\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i^2} \right) .$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

let $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ ,then for some  $k\in \mathbb{N}$ prove :$$ \left  ( \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} {b_i}^2} \right)  \le   k \left (\sqrt{  \sum_{i=1}^\infty  b_i^2} \right) .$$
I think if  ${a_i} \le {b_i}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i \le \sum_{i = 1}^\infty b_i$ ? now we have $ \frac{1}{i^2} {b_i}^2 \le {b_i}^2$ and then $ \left  (  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} {b_i}^2 \right)  \le    \left (  \sum_{i=1}^\infty  b_i^2 \right) $ and we know that is $x \le y $ then $\sqrt {x}\le\sqrt {y} $ .is this way true ?

Comment: It seems to be equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} {b_i}^2   \le   \sum_{i=1}^\infty k^2 b_i^2$, and since $\frac{1}{i^2} \leq k^2$ ...

Answer (score 1):

$k=1$ is valid because $\frac{1}{i^2}\leq1.$